# Javascript highlight line in div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a div that lists records from localStorage. Using Javascript I'd like to be able to select a line by clicking on it and highlight that line in order to delete it later on using a button.

I've tried different approaches I found on the internet with jQuery (not preferable since I don't use it anywhere else) and the `span` tag to select the line. However I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

```html
<div id="history" style=""></div>
```

```js
function setHistory() {
  var entry = "<span style='float:left;'>Date</span>[Time (no break), recup]<br>",
    keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
    revkeys = keys.sort().reverse(),
    i = 0,
    key;

  for (; key = revkeys[i]; i++) {
    entry = entry + "<span class='' style='float:left;'>" + key + "</span>" + localStorage.getItem(key) + "<br>";
  }
  if (keys == "" || keys == null)
    entry = "No previous data yet :("
  document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = entry;
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps using jQuery like this would be better? https://jsfiddle.net/gL9zmuow/

Comment: You could look into `classList` - add/remove/toggle, or setting `className`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to Vanilla JS, you could try adding the following:

```
    handleSpanClick = (e) => {
       if(e.target.tagName === "SPAN"){
        e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
       }
    }
    //run the lines below on document ready after page load
    document.querySelector("#history").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        handleSpanClick(evt);
    });
```

What it will do is it will set a click event Listener on the history DIV. If you click a span within that div, it will toggle the class "selected"